# Execute Provider from Map inside library flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am separating my Provider from FutureBuilder components into library Map so that I can use it as dynamic and reusable content. Here is the short version of how it look:

**page.dart (library)**

```
library myproj;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '--path/to/my/provider'

Map<String, dynamic> firstPage = {
  'text': 'This is the first page',
  'action': <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {
      'text': 'Next Page',
      'page': 2,
      'provider': (BuildContext context) =>
          Provider.of<Pages>(context, listen: false).checkNextPageCondition()
    }
  ]
};
```

**component.dart(component that use the library)**

```
{
    ...,
    FutureBuilder(
      future: isolate-function(),
      initialData: {...},
      builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        return Column(
          children:[
            for(var el in snapshot.data['action']) TextButton(
              onPressed:(){
                el['provider'];
              },
              child: Text(el['text'])
            )
          ]
        )
      }
    )

}
```

This has been heavily redacted code, but what I am trying to achieve here, is to pass the `Provider.of<Pages>(context, listen: false).checkNextPageCondition()` to the TextButton `onPressed` so it can trigger the function that I have defined in my Provider. But when I click the button, nothing happened, and there isn't a single error showing up in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  'text': 'Next Page',
  'page': 2,
  'provider': Provider.of<Pages>(context, listen: false).checkNextPageCondition()
}
```